# How does the GM split the exp in Earthdawn?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

If a crakbill is worth 60 Legend points, should i give each character 60 or a fraction of the exp derived from the number of PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered by the Gamemaster section on awarding Legend Points that starts on page 241. Specifically, "Defeating Creatures And Opponents" on page 242 says that the points are divided evenly among the characters who defeated the creature.

Note that defeating opponents is not the only source of LP in a session and the wider rules for Legend Awards may cap how many points a single PC gains from a confrontation, possibly resulting in none at all. The whole chapter should be consulted to understand Legend Awards.

Comment: oooh, i've read the whole book like 3 times and i missed that? and then i thought crakbill were giving a lot for what they were worth. Thanks a million.

Comment: Say, if a creature is worth 100, and the team is made of 4 adepts, but one of the adept is killed, should his part be splitted or his XP just disappear? Or it depends how much the character helped (dying of a critical hit at round 1 VS dying of the poison of the creature just as he slain it heroically?

Comment: @Mouhgouda We can't answer questions well in comments; if you have a new related question, please do ask it as a new question! :)