# How are Legend Points from creatures split when one PC died in the fight?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

Say, if a creature is worth 100 LP, and the party is made of 4 adepts, but one of the adepts is killed, is their share split among the survivors or does their XP just disappear?

Does it depend on how much the character helped (e.g., dying of a critical hit in the first round versus dying of the creature's poison just as they heroically slay it)?

Somewhat related to [this previous post](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48386/how-does-the-gm-split-the-exp-in-earthdawn/).

Answer (score 1):

In most systems:

**Ultimately that player did contribute to the encounter and did make it easier for them than just going in with just 3. The dead player takes up his normal share of experience (even if he cant make use of it due to death)**

Comment: This is almost always system-specific and therefore I've actually removed all mention of "system agnostic" from the question. (The question would have been closed as either "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based" if it were left system agnostic.) You may want to adjust the answer.

Comment: I can only answer this from a systems agnostic POV or other systems I am more familiar with. Would you advise I delete my answer as it doesn't technically fall under its parameters now?

Comment: You really should make it clear the answer isn't based on the text but on your experiences with other game systems.

Comment: @TechImp A note on your tag wiki edits: please don't "talk to the reader" in them. Our tag wikis aren't instruction manuals, they're merely explanations of what the tag is referring to. Also be aware that many of your tag wikis appear to be very, *very* D&D-centric and edition-centric. You may want to back off from referring to specific mechanical implementations of concepts in the wikis.